# Ignore multiple fieldnames in csv file using python?

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a .csv file that comes directly from an excel spreadsheet. There are multiple headers, and I wish to user the second row of headers as fieldnames. For example, I could have the following .csv file:

```
First Name, Last Name, User Name 
givenName, familyName, userName 
kit, harrington, kharrington 
rachael, mcadams, rmcadams
```

When I'm reading this, I'm really only concerned about the second row of filednames (givenName, familyName, etc.).

However, the csv module in Python uses the first row for the fieldnames, so I'm wondering what's the most "pythonic" way to bypass this?

For example, if I wanted to print all the names under "familyName," I would try to do the following:

```
with open('csv_file.csv','rb') as infile, open('other_csv_file.csv','wb') as outfile:

    r = csv.DictReader('csv_file')
    w = csv.DictWriter('other_csv_file', r.fieldnames)
    w.writeheader()

    for row in r:
        print row['familyName']
```

Comment: Skip the first row (e.g. with `next(r)`) before passing the file to the `DictReader`?

Comment: That's a great suggestion, thanks! I don't see why that wouldn't work, but I am also curious if this is the most appropriate way to handle this?

Comment: I think it probably is the most appropriate way; it is explicit about what you want to do (i.e. ignore the first line, then use the second as headers and the rest as rows) without being unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: Use pandas.  It lets you specify the row to use as the header.

Comment: Thank you guys very much! And thanks @jonrsharpe for pointing out that question! I should have searched more prior to asking! Lesson learned. =]